# AWS Create ONTAP volume from existing Storage Virtual Machines(SVM)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, ontap

I want to create an `AWS ONTAP Volume` only **Based on the existing Storage Virtual Machines(SVM)** .

I have `SVM` ID and `Name` are available with me in order to  use then in the new stack which i am creating to spin the new Volume(s).

My SVM ID is : `svm-04c2e2830ff42097e`.

**I tried Below:**  But did not worked.

```
---
Description: "Create FSx for ONTAP Filesystem"
Resources:
  AWSDemoVolume:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::Volume"
    Properties:
      Name: AWSBackupDemovol001
      OntapConfiguration:
        JunctionPath: /AWSBackupDemovol001
        SizeInMegabytes: 150
        StorageEfficiencyEnabled: true
        StorageVirtualMachineId: 
        - !ImportValue "svm-04c2e2830ff42097e"
        TieringPolicy:
          CoolingPeriod: 0
          Name: AUTO          
      VolumeType: "ONTAP"
      Tags:
        - Key: "Bacup_Tag"
          Value: "backup"
        - Key: "Created_By"
          Value: "Cloud Micron"
Outputs:
  FileSystemId:
    Value: !Ref "AWSdemocluster"
  SvmId:
    Value: !Ref "AWSDemosvm"
...
```

Comment: Please suggest or help.. `how i can deploy a Volume based on exiting SVM or Cluster` on aws FsxN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try which below ..

I have encountered same issue before. There is catch in the template below where as per documentation it says clearly that it needs `string` thus you don't required `!ImportValue` here. just remove that, please look at the [AWS DOC HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-fsx-volume-ontapconfiguration.html#cfn-fsx-volume-ontapconfiguration-storagevirtualmachineid)

Secondly, there is also another problem in the below code as you defined the `CoolingPeriod: 0` which is not correct as value can not be zero either it should be minimum `2` or greater.

```
---
Description: "Create FSx for ONTAP Filesystem"
Resources:
  AWSDemoVolume:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::Volume"
    Properties:
      Name: AWSBackupDemovol001
      OntapConfiguration:
        JunctionPath: /AWSBackupDemovol001
        SizeInMegabytes: 150
        StorageEfficiencyEnabled: true
        StorageVirtualMachineId: "svm-04c2e2830ff42097e"
        TieringPolicy:
          CoolingPeriod: 2
          Name: AUTO          
      VolumeType: "ONTAP"
      Tags:
        - Key: "Bacup_Tag"
          Value: "backup"
        - Key: "Created_By"
          Value: "Cloud Micron"
...
```